# The definition of Mordell operator.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I read the book of Kazuya Kato——"Number Theory: Iwasawa theory and modular forms".
In the proof of Mordell's proof of Ramanujan's conjecture,
[image]

he constructed "Mordell operator"
[image]

I've known his proof,
but still don't known how the motivation of his construction.
The appearance of "Mordell operator" is a little strange,
can anybody explain the motivation?
Besides, he said the "Mordell operator" can be generalized to "Hecke operator",
and it is much more complicated......
So, I just begin with the "simpler" case.

Any help will be appreciated.:)

---

Thanks for @David Loeffler's answer, and I read serre's book further.
He used lattice to define Hecke operator,

[image]

and then derive how it looks like.
Besides, he calculates the example of Eisenstein series and $\Delta$-function.
For $\delta$ the corresponding eigenvalue is $\tau(n)$.

The definition of Hecke operator is much more simple and great.
However, I still wonder the motivation of the definition and what's the nature of it?

Thanks for @David Loeffler again~~ :)

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen the name "Mordell operators" before, but these are very well-known objects under their usual name of "Hecke operators", and googling for that name will bring up references by the hundred. Serre's book "A Course in Arithmetic" gives a very nice account in the special case of level one modular forms (like the $\Delta$ appearing here), which avoids much of the complication of the general case.

Comment: It's a good suggestion! I read sere's book and found him use lattice to define Hecke operator, and derive how it looks like. Thanks for your advice, but I still can't understand "transforms a lattice to the sum of its sub-lattices of index n" to definite Hecke operator. I will edit it to make my question clear.